# Modulo in modulo operation vs in congruence relations.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, definition, congruence-relations

Is the "modulo" in modulo operation and in congruence relations, the same?

I don't know how the definitions go but I'm going to try to define modulo operation in my own words.

**Modulo operation:** Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ then a function $\cdot \bmod n : \mathbb{Z} \to \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, n-1\}$ given by $a \bmod n = r$ where $r$ is the remainder left when $a$ is divided by $n$, is called the modulo operation.

However, with that definition, I strongly suspect that "modulo" used in congruence relation is not the same. Because $a \equiv b \ (\bmod n) \Leftrightarrow n \mid (a-b) $ where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a binary relation and not a function.

Am I correct in believing that they're not the same? I can certainly think how they can be connected but I don't think they're the same. For example: $a \equiv b \ (\bmod n) \Leftrightarrow a \bmod n = b \bmod n$

Second question: What does one mean when they say "modular arithmetic", are they referring to Modulo operation or the congruence relations?

Comment: These are certainly very similar and closely related.  For what its worth, computer scientists tend to prefer the operation while mathematicians tend to prefer the congruence relation, but there is of course overlap and either group will use the other when it suits their needs.

Comment: As an aside, one should be particularly careful about the mod *operation* as it relates to negative values.  Some programming languages will have for instance $(-2)\%10 = 2$ rather than $(-2)\%10=8$ whereas the congruence relation has no such confusion, $-2\equiv 8\pmod{10}$ only.

Comment: @JMoravitz how did you get $-2 \bmod 10 = 2$? What definition of modulo operation are you using?

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm also confused by your wording "tend to prefer", if the concepts are different, I don't see how it makes sense to have a preference because they aren't alternatives to each other, no?

Comment: How did *I* get... no, how do various programming languages get... [See here for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720656/modulo-operation-with-negative-numbers?noredirect=1&lq=1).  My point was that if using negative numbers with modulo (*or remainder*) operator in a programming language it is worth confirming the behavior rather than assuming what it would be since it is not always consistent.

Comment: "*they aren't alternatives*"  I wouldn't say that... they share generally the same information albeit in slightly different formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, they are not the same. However, they are closely related. In fact, as you wrote,$$a\equiv b\pmod n\iff a\operatorname{mod}n=b\operatorname{mod}n,$$where the $\operatorname{mod}$ from the RHS is the module operation, whereas the one from the LHS is the one from congruence relations.

And modular arithmetic is about congruence relations.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation. Do you happen to know why we the use the word "modulo" in both cases. I understand  a word can have different meanings in different contexts but I was curious if there's anything specifically sepcial about the word "modulo"?

Comment: I don't know. I suggest that you post that question at the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site.